# OneNote - Orphaned notebooks still listed

Tags: windows, onedrive, microsoft-onenote

Microsoft OneNote (Version 16001.12026.20112.0) lists still orphaned, means already deleted notebooks. I would say I created them using OneNote 2016 Desktop, by the way I'm using the Microsoft Store version right now, and deleted them months ago. However they are still listed as you can see on the following image:

[image: OneNote Screendump]

Both of them are deleted! If I try to open it, an error occurred with the message "They are no longer available or the ownership is missing".

How could I remove them from this list using the OneNote **Microsoft Store Application**. Is there a cache to clean?

By the way, the listed path of each of them targets an URL starting with `https://d.docs.live.net/....`

Comment: Try to run "Office Upload Center > Settings > Delete Cached Files*.

Comment: I tried it right now, it doesn't solve my problem... Orphaned notebooks are still listed.

Comment: Can you right-click the notes and select "Remove from list"?

Comment: Of course I tried this :D... No context menu poped up, doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to uninstall the Microsoft Store version of OneNote.
This version is substandard and is abandoned by Microsoft and will never be
developed to the level of the desktop version.

You should download the desktop version of OneNote, which comes actually
from Office version 2016.

The download is found in the page
[Get OneNote on your PC and Macintosh for Free](https://www.onenote.com/download).
Click the "Free Download" button to download, then execute the setup program.
You will now have in your Start menu two such:

[image]

The one you want is "OneNote 2016".

You may find more gory details in the article
[OneNote Is Lonely And Confused](https://www.brucebnews.com/2019/05/onenote-is-lonely-and-confused/).

Comment: The OneNote download mentioned above has the option to resend "Notebook to Recycle Bin" when rightclicking on the notebook. As message bar comes up at the top of the notebook page content that the notebook will be deleted in 60 days ! However, the Windows 10 version of OneNote does not have this delete option.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't Office 2016 and don't want to install it, just go to [office.com/](https://www.office.com/) logged in to your Microsoft account and delete the recent list.